# Apple keyboard Caps Lock LED doesn't light up though caps *are* locked

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, keyboard

I have an Apple keyboard (French disposition) that's always worked in all the GNU/Linux distributions I tried (Fedora, Ubuntu, Mint, Arch, Gentoo, Debian). Only with Raspbian do I have issues, the latest of which is that the Caps Lock key doesn't light up when caps are... well, locked. I mean upper-case letters appear when I type, the LED indicator embedded in the Caps Lock key is just not lit, which is annoying.

Has anyone had the issue and found a fix? I've used Rapbian Jessie Lite image to install the system and have updated/upgraded it, no change. My device is a Raspberry Pi 2 model B, version 1.1 manufactured in 2014.

Answer (score 1):

The problem turns out to be a bug in Debian, as per this [Q/A on unix.stackexchange.com](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136817). The following command appears to temporarily fix the issue:

```
echo keycode 58 = Caps_Lock |sudo loadkeys -
```